# Color Sensor/hi-tech and EV3

Tags: ev3

I want to create a line follower by EV3 using hi-tech color sensor without using switch! :( I tried some former ways but the robot cannot follow the line very well!
can anyone guide me?

Comment: Can you be more specific about a particular a part of the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

This is from page 87 of a [document](http://home.earthlink.net/~dfrevert/fll/fll_programming_101_ev3_on_nxt.pdf) showing how to run NXT bricks using EV3-G software.

[image: proportional line following]

It uses the light sensor, not color sensor.  You'll want to set the mode of the color sensor.

Inside a loop that will stop following a line if the left button on the brick is pressed.

Basically, the steering value of the motors is taken from the light sensor reading.